# Syntax error in MySQL THEN trigger

Tags: mysql

I have these 2 triggers, but both give a syntax error at "THEN", and I cant figure out why. All tables are as they're called and so on, and I start it in delimiter:

```
CREATE TRIGGER capacity
AFTER INSERT ON Participants
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF  (NEW.status = 'a' AND
    (SELECT capacity FROM rooms WHERE room = NEW.PID) > (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Participants WHERE meetID = NEW.meetID) THEN DELETE FROM Participants WHERE PID = NEW.PID AND meetID = NEW.meetID;
    END IF;
    END $$

CREATE TRIGGER iraLikesBeer
AFTER INSERT ON  Meetings
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF ( NEW.what LIKE '%beer%' AND 'ira' NOT IN(SELECT pid FROM Participants WHERE meetid = 'NEW.meetid') THEN
    INSERT INTO Participants
    VALUES (NEW.meetID,'ira', 'u');
END IF;
    END $$
```

Comment: perhaps you need to close the ife, before then `)`

Comment: IF is not closed properly, add ")" before THEN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your trigger definitions have imbalanced parentheses.

```
IF  (NEW.status = 'a' AND (SELECT ...) > (SELECT ...) THEN ...
    ^
```

The first opening paren does not have a close paren.

The same problem exists in your second trigger.

Comment: Yeah, guess Ive stared blind at it.. typical. So sorry guys :(